# How do I remove a the Users group from everyone's user profile folder in Windows 7/2008?

Tags: windows, permissions, icacls

I am forced to add a user who may only have access to one folder.  Therefore, I need to remove the users and domain users permissions from all of my files.  Right now, every users can see eachother's folder.  All the Users folders have read permissions for the builtin "DOMAIN\Users" group, I would like to remove this.  I tried running in the users folder:

```
for /d %G in (*) do icacls %G /remove Users /t"
```

and it is doing something to all the files and folders, but when I go back and check, the Users permission is still there.

Comment: `icacls /?` says syntax `… /remove[:[g|d]] Sid`. You need to use _SID_. To obtain _SID_ for the  `BUILTIN\Users` local group, parse `whoami /groups /FO CSV` or `wmic path win32_group where "Caption='%ComputerName%\\Users'" get Sid`.  Google for _Get SID from AD (Active Directory) User / Group_ if you need it.

Comment: @JosefZ: It also has a note that "SIDs may be given in numerical _or_ friendly-name form"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `/remove` does not affect inherited ACLs:

```
C:\Windows\System32> pushd d:\bat\files2

d:\bat\files2> for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /T | findstr /I "folder \\Users"
folder BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
folder\xxx.csv BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
               BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)

d:\bat\files2> for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /remove Users /T
processed file: folder
processed file: folder\xxx.csv
Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files

d:\bat\files2> for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /T | findstr /I "folder \\Users"
folder BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
       BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
folder\xxx.csv BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
               BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
```

One needs to **disable inheritance and copy the ACEs first**:

```
d:\bat\files2> for /d %G in (*) do @(icacls %G /inheritance:d /T&&icacls %G /remove Users /T)
processed file: folder
processed file: folder\xxx.csv
Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files
processed file: folder
processed file: folder\xxx.csv
Successfully processed 2 files; Failed processing 0 files

d:\bat\files2> for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /T | findstr /I "folder \\Users"
folder BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
folder\xxx.csv BUILTIN\Administrators:(F)
```

Note the use of [`&&` operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in the following one-liner

```
for /d %G in (*) do @(icacls %G /inheritance:d /T&&icacls %G /remove Users /T)
```

instead of

```
for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /inheritance:d /T
for /d %G in (*) do @icacls %G /remove Users /T
```

**Example** applied to the following file structure:

```
d:\bat\files2> tree . /f

D:\BAT\FILES2
│   SampleInput.eml
│
└───folder
        xxx.csv
```